# Не работает кеширование в Picasso

Tags: android, кэширование, picasso

Добавил зависимость  `implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'`, в `MyApplication`:

```
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    Picasso built = builder.build();
    built.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
```

И добавил: `.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)`
Но теперь вообще ничего не загружается. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй это:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

В Picasso кэширование включено по умолчанию.
и а также другие параметры, которые используются в memoryPolicy(,)

```
Picasso 
    .with(context) 
    .load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[1]) 
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE) 
.into(imageViewFromDisk);
```